# How to sum up fractions from integer divisions inside a float variable?

Tags: c

I am writing a simple C program that prints the sum of the harmonic series like:

```
1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ...... + 1/n
```

My program is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main(){
     int n,i;
     float num=0, tmp=0;
     scanf("%d", &n);
     for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
        tmp = 1/i;
        num = num + tmp;
     }
     printf("%f", num);
}
```

As per my understanding, if `n=4`, the output must be: `2.03333` 
But the output comes as `1.00000`

Comment: To be nitpicking, the output "must be" 2.0**8**3333 ;) Also, it should be `int main(void){...}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1/i` is not a float value, it is an int of value 0 or 1, because of integer division rules.
The value is 1 for 1/1 otherwise 0. Adding all of them up results in 1.

This is a floating point value:

```
1.0/i
```

Adding them up should give the desired result.

To be precise, I should say that `1.0` is a `double`.
In order to work with actually a `float` value to match the `float` variable, use `1.0f`. Both are floating point values in contrast to integer values.

Comment: I would like to cordially invite the downvoter to explain. I promise not to revenge-downvote. For a matter-of-fact hint at a shortcoming of my answer, I even promise to say thanks.

Comment: I try not to worry about random downvotes; it's usually not worth the energy.  One guess (this is only a guess) is that someone felt this question was so old, so frequent, that you should not have rewarded the asker by answering at all.  (I'm not saying that; I sometimes like answering frequent questions, too.)

Comment: @SteveSummit Thanks for your input. In case somebody finds this to be a duplicate, please flag or close-vote. If the linked Q/A convinces me, I will even add mine.

Comment: @Eric Well that is a valid point. I used "floating point" (not "float") in order to simplify. But I will add some details.

Comment: @Eric Done. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 3):

As `1` and `i` are integers, dividing these two will be integer and you will get `0` for `i > 1` in this case. You can cast `i` using `(float)i` and you will have `1/(float)i`.